# Coordinate [turn] option in foreach

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach

I am trying to recreate a triangle spiral(red) with a `foreach` -but the `turn` option does not behave nicely - it seems to turn less and less each time. Is there an explanation? What am I doing wrong?

Here I use `90` degree angle and length `1`, just to illustrate:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1 cm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\newcommand{\x}{0.872}
\draw[red] (0,0) -- (1,0)
  -- ([turn]125:\x^1)
  -- ([turn]125:\x^2) 
  -- ([turn]125:\x^3) 
  -- ([turn]125:\x^4) 
  -- ([turn]125:\x^5) 
  -- ([turn]125:\x^6) 
  -- ([turn]125:\x^7) 
  -- ([turn]125:\x^8) 
  -- ([turn]125:\x^9) 
  -- ([turn]125:\x^10);
\draw (0,0) -- (1,0) foreach \i in {1,...,50} {-- ([turn]90:1)};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Red triangle spiral and large black spiral]

**Edit:**

With `\draw (0,0) -- (1,0) foreach \i in {1,...,10} { -- ([turn]125:\x^\i)};`  I get:

[image: Different red and black spirals]

Comment: Just to clarify, you expect the code in the second statement to produce a black square (with each side being drawn ~12 times)?

Comment: Yes. And I would expect this to recreate red spiral `\draw (0,0) -- (1,0) foreach \i in {1,...,10} { -- ([turn]125:\x^\i)};` (but it does not)

Comment: It seems that is  a bug!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I agree with [Black Mild in comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/140722/black-mild) that this seems a `tikz` bug, and has reported it here: https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/issues/1047.

A possible fix:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\makeatletter
% see https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/blob/85d2c38b78407e5b1ba42140dfd11fcdf8df1edf/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/tikz.code.tex#L2582-L2616
\def\tikz@foreach{%
  \def\pgffor@beginhook{%
    \tikz@lastx=\tikz@foreach@save@lastx%
    \tikz@lasty=\tikz@foreach@save@lasty%
    \tikz@lastxsaved=\tikz@foreach@save@lastxsaved%
    \tikz@lastysaved=\tikz@foreach@save@lastysaved%
    \let\tikz@tangent=\tikz@foreach@save@tangent % added
    \setbox\tikz@figbox=\box\tikz@tempbox%
    \setbox\tikz@figbox@bg=\box\tikz@tempbox@bg%
    \expandafter\tikz@scan@next@command\pgfutil@firstofone}%
  \def\pgffor@endhook{\pgfextra{%
      \xdef\tikz@foreach@save@lastx{\the\tikz@lastx}%
      \xdef\tikz@foreach@save@lasty{\the\tikz@lasty}%
      \xdef\tikz@foreach@save@lastxsaved{\the\tikz@lastxsaved}%
      \xdef\tikz@foreach@save@lastysaved{\the\tikz@lastysaved}%
      \global\let\tikz@foreach@save@tangent=\tikz@tangent % added
      \global\setbox\tikz@tempbox=\box\tikz@figbox%
      \global\setbox\tikz@tempbox@bg=\box\tikz@figbox@bg%
      \pgfutil@gobble}}%
  \def\pgffor@afterhook{%
    \tikz@lastx=\tikz@foreach@save@lastx%
    \tikz@lasty=\tikz@foreach@save@lasty%
    \tikz@lastxsaved=\tikz@foreach@save@lastxsaved%
    \tikz@lastysaved=\tikz@foreach@save@lastysaved%
    \let\tikz@tangent=\tikz@foreach@save@tangent % added
    \let\pgffor@beginhook\relax%
    \let\pgffor@endhook\relax%
    \let\pgffor@afterhook\relax%
    \setbox\tikz@figbox=\box\tikz@tempbox%
    \setbox\tikz@figbox@bg=\box\tikz@tempbox@bg%
    \tikz@scan@next@command}%
  \global\setbox\tikz@tempbox=\box\tikz@figbox%
  \global\setbox\tikz@tempbox@bg=\box\tikz@figbox@bg%
  \global\let\tikz@foreach@save@tangent=\tikz@tangent % added
  \xdef\tikz@foreach@save@lastx{\the\tikz@lastx}%
  \xdef\tikz@foreach@save@lasty{\the\tikz@lasty}%
  \xdef\tikz@foreach@save@lastxsaved{\the\tikz@lastxsaved}%
  \xdef\tikz@foreach@save@lastysaved{\the\tikz@lastysaved}%
  \foreach}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\newcommand{\x}{0.872}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0,0) -- (1,0) foreach \i in {1,...,50} {-- ([turn]90:1)};
  
  \draw[xshift=2cm] (0,0) -- (1,0) foreach \i in {1,...,10} { -- ([turn]125:\x^\i)};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

output:
[image]

---

To save some lines,

```tex
\usepackage{regexpatch}

\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd*\tikz@foreach
  {\tikz@lastysaved=\tikz@foreach@save@lastysaved}
  {\tikz@lastysaved=\tikz@foreach@save@lastysaved
   \let\tikz@tangent=\tikz@foreach@save@tangent}
  {}{\PatchFailed}

\xpatchcmd*\tikz@foreach
  {\xdef\tikz@foreach@save@lastysaved{\the\tikz@lastysaved}}
  {\xdef\tikz@foreach@save@lastysaved{\the\tikz@lastysaved}%
   \global\let\tikz@foreach@save@tangent=\tikz@tangent}
  {}{\PatchFailed}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping that I could just use an extra pair of parentheses or something stupid like that. Is your fix just for this specific case, or is it more like an actual repair of TikZ?

Comment: It tries to fix `turn` used in `foreach` loop body.

Answer (score 7):

It seems like `foreach` doesn't work well with `[turn]`. I couldn't find a way to fix your issue. Anyway, I suggest that you use only the robust commands to do that. Maybe like this:

[image: foreach lines]

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \def\x{0.87}
        \draw (0,0) foreach \i in {1,...,50} {--++(125*\i:3*\x^\i)};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I can not remember, but are there not a relative low limit on what angle is allowed in polar coordinates? -I am surprised that `125*50` is accepted.

Comment: Actually, I suspected a `dimension too large` error to happen, but it didn't. Don't really know if there's a substatntial limit. We could try.

Comment: By test the angle accepts: `-16383.99999` to `16383.99999`. -but the manual page 138 says: "The angle must always be given in degrees and should be between
−360 and 720."